# How to format array of values to form a distribution for google-charts histogram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, google-visualization, histogram

I have 1000 values in no particular order but I'd like to format them into a normal distribution to plot on a histogram using google-charts.

I've tried using d3.js and I got it working just based off some examples but it looks extremely ugly and I don't have enough time to learn d3 in and out to get the results I want. Google-charts visual format are great.

The problem is google-charts expects data in a format where each value has a name along with headers. So when I organized it into this:

```
'dsSample1': [
    ['price', 'number'],
    ['price', 11386.057139142767],
    ['price', 27659.397260273952],
    ['price', 44159.39726027395],
    ...
```

from

```
'dsSample2': [
    11386.057139142767,
    27659.397260273952,
    44159.39726027395,
    28026.04112639835,
    ...
```

google charts works, but I get the following:

[image]

This is as close as I've come to getting it working in d3: https://jsfiddle.net/0jtrq17x/1/. It works but it's extremely ugly.

I've managed to arrange the array data into bins using some d3 code but it is imcompatible with google-charts and I don't know to make it compatible, and also don't know how to format the data so it plays nice with google-charts histogram

**this code**

```
var values = this.hypo.dsSample2.map(x => {
    return x + 128608.42487322348
})
var max = d3.max(values)
var min = d3.min(values)
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range([0, 800]);
var histGenerator = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(100))
    (values)
this.data1 = histGenerator
```

**returns this array transformation**

[image]

My problem is I don't know how to massage my array of data so I can get something like this in google-charts:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two [data formats](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#data-format) for the google charts version.
a single series format, with the names,
or a multi-series format, with just the numbers.
it is ok to use the multi-series format with a single series.

so, assigning names is not required.
but you will have to convert each value to its own array.

```
'dsSample1': [
    [11386.057139142767],
    [27659.397260273952],
    [44159.39726027395],
    ...
```

from

```
'dsSample2': [
    11386.057139142767,
    27659.397260273952,
    44159.39726027395,
    ...
```

you can use the `map` method to format the data.

```
dsSample.map(function (value) {
  return [value];
});
```

see following fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/x684f1vs/

Comment: perfect. the error was because i was using vuejs and the API for that component didn't have an option for `opt_firstRowIsData` like googles visualization api does. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you have decided against D3, but since your question is still tagged with d3.js, I will post an answer using D3 anyways :)

I have made an updated JSFiddle, with an adaption of your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/w7r80cfo/1/

In short, to manipulate this histogram, look to the following lines:

- 1038 and 1039 to change the dimensions (width and height respectively) of the visualization. The values given are in pixels.
- 1049 to change the number of buckets for you histogram. Currently it is set to 100.
- 1083 to change the width of the individual bars. Currently, I've set it to `0.25` of the space calculated for each bar. If you e.g. change `0.25` to `1` the bars will be so wide, they will be drawn right next to each other.
- 1085 to change the color of the bars. Currently they are given a darker shade of red the higher number of values they represent. If you want e.g. just blue, change the line to `.attr("fill", "steelblue")`

Play around with these values and see if you can get to a chart that is close to what you want.

To elaborate a bit on the changes I've made, they consist mainly of the following:

**Line 1038**: lowered the `width` to `600`.

**Line 1073**: updated to position the visualization correctly:

```
.attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
```

**Line 1083**: lowered the width of the bars by multiplying by 0.25:

```
.attr("width", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) * 0.25)
```

Other than that I have removed the following code to remove the text labels, as they indeed made the chart look messy:

```
bar.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".75em")
  .attr("y", -12)
  .attr("x", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) / 2)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return "$" + d3.format(",.2f")(d.x); });
```

Besides this, I have added an y axis and changed the way the axes are drawn in order to make them look a bit nicer. I can go into detail about these changes, but I think they are of lesser interest to your goal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: damn great work thank you, im going to passively work on the d3 graph and when its up to snuff and i know more i'll switch to it.